# What is a good surface material for testbenching a computer?

Tags: computer-building

It appears it will be a while before the case for my new PC will be available, but I will have all the other parts. Therefore, I will likely run it without a case for a while (hopefully not long).

But is a wooden table a suitable surface for it (and the other components) to sit on?

Comment: It's certainly better than a metal table ;)

Comment: Indeed... and better for any http://thedailywtf.com/ referencing.

Comment: Be sure to have something metal around to touch occasionally, this will discharge any static electricity you may have accumulated moving around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. Basically, anything not conductive or susceptible to static electricity is fine.

Friend of mine didn't trust any surface and just hung all the components by strings from the ceiling.

Comment: You gotta post pics!

Comment: This is not his (it was a long time ago), but you get the idea: http://www.geekologie.com/2007/10/sky_puter_case_mod_provides_go.php

Answer (score 2):

Wooden is great for its nonconductive properties. Covering it with a hard rubber mat can be very helpful to minimize dings and bums and to prevent sliding. You should be able to find either mid-quality cabinet covers or even the foam matting used to adhere carpets to hard flooring. Apply a light coat of mild glue to the wood and just lay out the mat.

A flat mat is best (as opposed to a mesh) as a mesh can "eat" screws and small bits unless the mesh is fine enough.

Answer (score 1):

I have a computer that I took out of it's case because I wanted to fit in a bigger graphics card than could fit in the slimline case. I didn't want it to just lay around on my table and collect static, so I put it in a old printer paper box that was laying around:

[image: Cardboard computer case]

Bringing a whole new meaning to "cardboard box"