# Can I build or test a computer without a case?

Tags: computer-building

I am in the process of building a really nice new PC right now.  It's going to have a nice Lian Li case with the internals powder coated black and all the wires will be sleeved.  So my problem is I am getting parts in a couple days but my case will not be completed for about a month because it is on back order plus time to powder coat it.  I am purchasing many of m y parts from newegg.com and they claim you must return any dead parts within 30 days or the invoice for there warranty to replace bad parts.

So is it possible for me to set up the PC without a case just to test that the main parts are working correctly within the timeframe I am allowed?

If this is possible, how do I deal with turning the system on/off without a power button?  Or is there one on a motherboard?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/868/surface-material-for-testbench-operation-of-pc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put together computers without cases all the time. For PCIe/PCI add-in card bracket clearance, you need something to raise the PCB off the table like standoffs that screw into the mounting holes, or something nonconductive that can handle < 100°C or so without bursting into flames. Usually a motherboard will power up when you plug in the AC or go into standby. This could be a BIOS option (power state after unexpected AC power loss). You'll need to short the two pins of the power header to turn it if there isn't a button on the board.

Comment: I haven't built a PC in a while, but some P4's used to require the CPU heatsink to be screwed directly through the motherboard into the case or at least into standoffs.

Comment: thanks, I just found something that might be useful too here http://www.frozencpu.com/products/8756/ele-414/FrozenCPU_ATX_Control_Kit_0014.html?tl=g4c157s483 it says "This little kit puts your ATX switches, speaker, and status LEDs right on your motherboard"

Comment: Modern processors typically do require a thermal solution that screws into something.

That kit looks interesting. In the past, I'd just wired up the switches myself (but I have a fully stocked electronics lab at work).